# Used logic in view, how to get it out

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

For a project I used some logic in my view, this is not the way to go so I want to get it out.

The problem is that it can't be done from a class method of my model because Zend will make 10000 of queries from 10000 of instances to the database and it becomes very slow.

So I have to do it on a way that it loads all data at once, then processes it and returns the data back to the view. In my view it works the way I do it, the only problem is that it is IN the viewfiles.

What is the way to go? Just make a class in the model that inputs the values and returns required data?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't really fully understand where you have problems here? Can you give a short example?

Comment: I have to do comparisons on huge amounts of data from a database. I noticed that, since I use lazy loading, that when I load the data from the methods of the instances it takes ages. When I load all data at once (in one query) it takes a few seconds. So I used the loading and comparison logic in the view, it only has to do one litte colorize thing. But I want to get the logic out of my view, so how should I do that?

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. How hard it be to move your logic to a model or at least an action of your controller? :/

Comment: @baklap - since you prefer to let people (framework) teach you how to code, so, no reason for you to regret now ...

Comment: Perhaps moving your logic into view helper might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way i would go to display data from a MVC perspective

**Controller**

```
function someAction(){
    $someTable = new Model_DbTable_SomeTable();
    $allData = $someTable->fetchAll();

    $arrayFormattedData = DataProcessor::process($allData);

    $this->view->data = $arrayFormattedData;
}
```

You have to do your logic processing in a model (in the example above its done in the static class DataProcessor throught the process method (Not neccessarly the way to go, but it could be a good start)

**View**

```
echo $this->dataParser($this->data); // using a view helper to parse data to be displayed
```

or

```
echo $this->partialLoop('partialLoop.phtml', $this->data); // using the partial loop view helper built in in ZF
```

Finally, you should try to make your models as flexible as possible to make them **reusable** which is the key in oop development.